# Cannot start Android Emulator with Android-N. Error: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-7.0-nougat

When I try run an AVD with Android N (Using Stable Version of Android Studio), I get the following error. Below are screenshots of the AVD Settings also.

[image]

Below are the settings for my AVD:

[image]

[image]